# php - get value of variables defined in shell script

Tags: php, shell, exec

How can I get value of a variable defined in a shell script? (the script is a configuration file, only contains variable-definitions) I cannot use "source" command in exec:

```
echo exec('var=2; echo $var'); //writes "2"
echo exec('source config.sh; echo $var'); //writes ""
```

How can I get value of variables defined in a shell script?

Comment: Have you checked it is the correct path? Try with absolute path to see if `config.sh` is requested properly.

Comment: yes, I use absolute path in my code (the problem exists that way too) - and the path is correct, the command runs well in terminal

Comment: I found a related question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302958/is-it-possible-to-source-a-sh-file-using-php-cli-and-access-exported-env-vars

Answer (score 2):

userThis worked for me just now on the terminal:

```
echo var=2 > shellscript
echo "<?php echo exec('source /home/user/shellscript; echo $var'); ?>" > phpscript.php
ls | grep script
phpscript.php
shellscript
php phpscript.php 
2
```

So I wrote the shellscript, then a php to read the shell script and ran the php script. It did just what you wanted.

Maybe you can add the other exec components to get a clue?

```
<?php 
echo exec('source /home/user/shellscript; echo $var',$out,$ret); 
echo "\nout0: ". $out[0]. "\nret: $ret\n";
?>
```

This shows me:

```
~]$ php phpscript.php 
2
out0: 2
ret: 0
```