# How to call a bash function from PHP?

Tags: php, bash

This is my workflow:

```
ubuntu$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

function getNumber
{
    echo 1
}


ubuntu$ cat test.php
<?php

echo shell_exec("getNumber");



ubuntu$ source test.sh 
ubuntu$ getNumber 
1

ubuntu$ php test.php 
sh: 1: getNumber: not found
```

Is it possible to change a php script (or may be its call) the way, so it will print "1"? I am looking for a way to *call a **bash function** from php*.

I've tried some solutions from here: [Is it possible to source a *.sh file using PHP CLI and access exported Env vars in the PHP script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302958/is-it-possible-to-source-a-sh-file-using-php-cli-and-access-exported-env-vars)

One of them was: `./test.sh && php -f test.php` - but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function that does what you want.  It loads spawns a bash process that sources the bash script, then runs the function.

It uses proc-open ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php )

```
<?php


$value = runBashFunction("test.sh", "getNumber");
var_dump($value);



function runBashFunction($bashfile, $bashfunction) {
    $descriptorspec = array(
         0 => array("pipe", "r"),    // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
         1 => array("pipe", "w"),    // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
         2 => array("pipe", "w") // stderr is a pipe too
    );

    $cwd = '.';
    $env = array();

    $process = proc_open('bash', $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd, $env);

    if (is_resource($process)) {
            fwrite($pipes[0], "source $bashfile\n");
            fwrite($pipes[0], "$bashfunction\n");
            fclose($pipes[0]);

            $output = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
            $error = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
            fclose($pipes[1]);
            fclose($pipes[2]);

            // It is important that you close any pipes before calling
            // proc_close in order to avoid a deadlock
            //

            $return_value = proc_close($process);
            //note, $error and $return_value are discarded
            return $output;
    }
    return null;
}
?>
```

Comment: It always prints int(1) even if I rename in your code `test.sh` to unexisting `test-whatever.sh`

Comment: Oops, I was returning the return_value instead of the output.  I have edited the script, please try again.

Comment: Thank you, @Tim. it looks like it works. Let me try it with some parameters.

Comment: It works with parameters and w/o them. It's a bit lenghty, but I don't have any other better working solution now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In this particular example, you can combine the `source` command and the function itself into the same PHP exec call:

```
var_dump(
    shell_exec('source test.sh && getNumber')
); // string(2) "1
"
```

Trim the result if you need to to remove the carriage return.

Comment: This is what it returns... `sh: 1: source: not found
NULL`

Comment: Which OS are you running?

Comment: Linux 3.13.0-37-generic x86_64. Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca

Comment: Yet `source test.sh && getNumber` works from your console?

Comment: That's correct and `source test.sh && getNumber` prints "1" as it should.

Comment: And you're running this script from the same directory as test.sh? You should try a couple of things - firstly try the full path to `test.sh` and secondly give it execute permissions for your web user and try again

Comment: My bad: I checked distro version on a wrong machine. Correct info is: 3.13.0-48-generic and Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Comment: I can reproduce a similar error by putting the wrong file path in, although the message is different for me (OSX) - try an absolute file path

Comment: Well, you can see my workflow - I didn't change directories - those commands were called one after another.

Comment: Agreed, appears to be a file access issue though - try either an absolute path to `test.sh` and/or give it execute permissions for the user

Comment: I get the same error as Axalix.  I think this is because "sh" doesn't have a "source" command.

For me, shell_exec runs sh instead of bash.  "source" is a bash builtin command, not an executable.

Comment: Cheers @TimSmith - maybe adding bash to the command might alleviate

Comment: @RobbieAverill - adding `bash` to the command actually helped!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to pass the name of the function you would like to execute into the bash script.

**test.sh** is the bash script with the function you would like to execute:

```
#!/bin/bash

function getNumber
{
    echo "fnGetNumber"
}

# Test if the first parameter names a function
if [ "$(type -t $1)" = function ]; then
    $1
else
    echo "$1 is an invalid function"
fi;
```

**test.php** is the PHP script that will call the function:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
echo `./test.sh getNumber`;
```

Note that this requires you pass the name of the script as well as the function name.

Credit for function test to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/85903/2182349

If you would like to pass a parameter to the function, you may use:

Updated **test.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash

function getNumber
{
    echo "fnGetNumber $1"
}

if [ "$(type -t $1)" = function ]; then
    $1 "$2"
else
    echo "$1 is an invalid function"
fi;
```

Updated **test.php**

```
<?php
$parm = 'toast';
echo `./test.sh getNumber $parm`;
```

Comment: it does work and technically my question is answered - there is one "although": is it possible to change your code so I can pass parameters to `getNumber`?

Comment: There may be multiple (random number) of parameters :)

Comment: Enclose the random number of parameters in quotes in PHP and pass them as one, then break them apart in the bash script.

Comment: Thank you. I don't think it is always possible to break them apart, especially when some commands look this way `rsync -aL --rsh="ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null"` Also I can't touch the bash script (it was in my question that I can only touch php and its call). The shell script is a library (list of functions) that I was given and I can't change it. php code is mine - I am free to make any changes I want.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution. The problem was in ***Ubuntu*** and its `dash`

Running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash` and answering `no` changed `dash` to `bash`, what made `source` command available from php.

**WAS**: `ls -la /bin/sh` => `/bin/sh -> dash`

**NOW**: `ls -la /bin/sh` => `/bin/sh -> bash`

With enabled `source`, this worked fine:
`echo shell_exec('source /full/path/to/file/test.sh && getNumber abc def');`

What helped me: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13702876/4621324

**One Note:** during the change Ubuntu has warned me: *Using dash as the system shell will improve the system's overall performance. It does not alter the shell presented to interactive*

---

As I don't really want to change `dash` to `bash` on the global level, I decided to go with this solution:

`echo shell_exec('/bin/bash -c "source /full/path/to/file/test.sh && getNumber abc def"');`